# Raspberry does not register to windows DNS server

Tags: server, windows, dns

It gets its local dynamic IP correctly assigned by dhcp from the windows server 2008r2. Also, the dns server is assigned correctly (can ping anything inside and outside my local network).

But i cannot ping the raspberry using "raspberry" or "raspberry.xxx.local". Looking into the windows servers dns management, there is not entry for the raspberry in the forward lookup zones.

What am i missing? Im interested in a "plain" solution, if possible without samba or else. Just want the rapsberry to register to the windows dns with its hostname.

Update I (followed the hints from RalfFriedl):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nsupdate
> update add raspberrypi.abcb.local 600 a 192.168.12.103
> send
couldn't get address for 'takamaka.abcb.local': not found

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup takamaka.abcb.local
Server:         192.168.12.10
Address:        192.168.12.10#53

Name:   takamaka.abcb.local
Address: 192.168.12.10
```

Why can't `nsupdate` resolve the DNS server IP, but `nslookup` and `host` do fine! `ping` doesn't resolve, too. The dhcp leases:

```
lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  fixed-address 192.168.12.103;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.12.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 691200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.12.10;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.12.10;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 345600;
  option ntp-servers 185.13.148.109,176.9.40.142;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 604800;
  option domain-name "abcb.local";
  renew 6 2019/02/09 14:18:17;
  rebind 2 2019/02/12 23:39:05;
  expire 3 2019/02/13 23:39:05;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you installed an RPF Raspbian image on your Pi... the default hostname is `raspberrypi` BTW: the same is true for the Pi: it's not a Raspberry but a Raspberry Pi. Also never seen 'hostname.xxx.local` I would expect `hostname` and/or `hostname.local`to work. The machine you're using this from needs to have avahi/zeroconf/bonjour installed for the .local version to work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake with the hostname. It's `raspberrypi`. But `raspberrypi.localdomain.local` is usual for local / active directory domains. As mentioned, i want a "plain" solutions. So avahi/zeroconf/bonjour is not what im looking for, rather what @RalfFriedl suggested below.

Comment: You have given the solution with Update II in your question. Please create an answer with the solution and accept it after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo just did as you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, had to remove `libnss-mdns` with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt-get remove libnss-mdns
```

I found this solution at [nslookup finds ip, but ping doesnt](https://askubuntu.com/a/81807/717636).

Answer (score 1):

As of [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) the (pseudo) top level domain **.local** is explicitly reserved for Multicast DNS. As so often Microsoft does not respect such official specifications and uses **.local** to manage local network segments its own way. Therefore it is known that

> The connection of Macintosh and Linux computers or zeroconf peripherals to Windows networks can be problematic if those networks include name servers that use .local as a search domain for internal devices. [<sup>(**ref)**</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local#Microsoft_recommendations).

There are many problems known and Microsoft has made some *Support article* to address this. You can find some hints to avoid the problems by looking at [Wikipedia - **.local** Microsoft recommendations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local#Microsoft_recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows server allows unauthenticated DNS updates, then a simple update with `nsupdate` without a key will do. Windows clients also used to send just an unauthenticated DNS update request, and the server would update the DNS entries as requested.

To send a DNS update request, use the `nsupdate` program:

```
NAME=raspberry.xxx.local
TTL=60
IP=1.2.3.4
echo "
update delete $NAME A
update add $NAME $TTL A $IP
send" | nsupdate /dev/stdin
```

Here `NAME` is the DNS name you want to register, `TTL` is the time to live in seconds and `IP` is your IP address.

Comment: I've tried this. But `nsupdate` can't resolve the DNS server name, although `nslookup` can do! What might there be wrong? (Edited the question and added results)